# How to trim the beginning of a field (reverse trim)?

Tags: views

In Views and several field formatting modules you are given the ability to trim the end of text fields to show for example only the first 100 characters. However what if I want to do the reverse. What if I want to trim a field to **not** show the first 100 characters but to show everything else, how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way would be to write your own view field plugin.

The quick way is as follows:
I assume your text field is the main body field.
Install views_php. In your view hide the text field. Add a Global PHP field. Make sure it is after the text field. In its output code put the following:

```
<?php print substr($data->field_body[0]['rendered']['#markup'], 100);?>
```

In Rewrite Results strip out HTML tags. As you are truncating text you will run into problems with unmatched tags, so you have to do this. Also, this sanitises the text. If you do not do this you have to run check_markup in the php.

Also, this is not the preferred way to output a field. The correct way is to use field_view_field.

And if your field is anything other than the body, then install devel module, and include this PHP snippet in the output code of the PHP field.

```
<?php print dsm($data);?>
```

This will help with getting the right field.

Comment: Ok I tried the above code, the field I am trying to use is the default comment body field whose D7 machine name should be "comment_body". So I tried the following:
<?php print substr($data->comment_body[0]['rendered']['#markup'], 100);?>

But this causes a PHP error:
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$comment_body in __lambda_func()

I am going to try to install the Devel module and see how I go. I have never used it before.

Comment: I cannot get your code to work. I have followed your instructions, but I keep getting errors. I have installed Devel module and if I try to use your second print statement it also causes an error.

Comment: Code for the comment body:    <?php print substr($data->field_comment_body[0]['rendered']['#markup'], 100);?>      This is just a primer. You still have to deal with issues such as what to do when the comment text is shorter than 100 characters.

Comment: Great this works, and I will use the Views Conditional module to test whether the comment has 100 characters or not. 


However, how could I add a word boundary to the trim in your code? I have tried using strpos to create the word boundary but I can't get it to work with your code above: substr($data->field_comment_body, 0, strpos($data->field_comment_body, ' ', 100))

Comment: [How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara)

Comment: I've tried the following code from your suggested page but it seems to have the same effect as your previous answer, the characters are simply cut but not based on words. `<?php print preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($data->field_comment_body[0]['rendered']['#markup'], 100));?>`

Comment: <?php

$output = strrev($data->field_comment_body[0]['rendered']['#markup']);
$max = 100;

    if(strlen($output)>$max)
    {
        $output = substr($output ,0,$max);
        $i = strrpos($output ," ");
        $output = substr($output ,0,$i);
        $output = $output ." ..... ";
    }

print strrev($output);

?>

Comment: This is definitely heading in the right direction as the code does display based on word boundary now, thanks for that. However it is only displaying the last 100 characters of the field, instead of displaying everything except the first 100 characters. How can this be fixed?

Comment: <?php

$output = strrev($data->field_comment_body[0]['rendered']['#markup']);
$len = strlen($output);
$max = 100;

    if($len-$max>=0)
    {
        $output = substr($output ,0,$len-$max);
        $i = strrpos($output ," ");
        $output = substr($output ,0,$i);
        $output = $output ." ..... ";
    }

print strrev($output);

?>